# DataView rowfilter always includes last of the set

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource, dataview, rowfilter

When using dataView.RowFilter I always get the filtered result including the last element of the dataset.

I have a test dataset:

```
private TestClass[] items =
{
    new TestClass{name = "Hans", age = 10 },
    new TestClass{name = "Bert", age = 5 },
    new TestClass{name = "Gerda", age = 41 },
    new TestClass{name = "Dolf", age = 73 },
    new TestClass{name = "Ludo", age = 35 },
};
```

Creating the dataview:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("TestItem", typeof(TestClass));
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

foreach(var item in items)
{
    dataView.AddNew(item.name, item.age, item);
}
```

setting the filter and datasource:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "[Name] = 'Hans'";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "TestItem";
comboBox1.DataSource = dataView;
```

This should return only Hans as result but for me this gives the results:
Hans and Ludo.

If I filter on 'Ludo' it results in only 'Ludo'.
Why does it always return the last element as well and how can I make sure it does only return the filtered set?

-edit

```
public static class DataViewExtensions
{
    public static DataRowView AddNew(this DataView dataView, params object[] parameters)
    {
        DataRowView dataRowView = dataView.AddNew();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            dataRowView[index++] = parameter;
        }

        return dataRowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am testing your code, and I don't have an overload for `DatView.AddNew(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, just [DatView.AddNew()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.addnew(v=vs.110).aspx). Have you overridden this method in a different namespace?

Comment: When filling the datatable instead of the dataView and then creating the dataview from the filled DataTable it works.

Comment: @djv Yeah I'm sorry that is a function that I use to not have to assign each column it self. Instead i made an extension that loops over the parameters to assign the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exception which others seem to get

> DataTable must be set prior to using DataView

(I suggest you put that in a search engine)

Although you don't get the exception, you should follow this order.

Fortunately, setting up the DataTable before the DataView can be done with less code, and no extension method.

```
TestClass[] items =
{
    new TestClass{name = "Hans", age = 10 },
    new TestClass{name = "Bert", age = 5 },
    new TestClass{name = "Gerda", age = 41 },
    new TestClass{name = "Dolf", age = 73 },
    new TestClass{name = "Ludo", age = 35 },
};

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("TestItem", typeof(TestClass));

// set up the DataTable first
foreach (var item in items)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(item.name, item.age, item);
}

// then use the DataView
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

dataView.RowFilter = "[Name] = 'Hans'";

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "TestItem";
comboBox1.DataSource = dataView;
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and research. This clears things up.